# Dropzon js sending empty POST Request (apparently) when images uploaded

Tags: java, jsp, dropzone.js

I am trying to use [Dropzone js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload multiple images with preview for a user form. I have implemented it using jsp servlet. But I am unable to get images on server side. The doPost method on server side is getting called when images are selected on dropzone component but HttpServletequest request is containing no image data (apparently). May be I am reading request data wrong or some other problem. Please help. I am using Netbeans 8.0.2, Wildfly 8.2 final, jdk 1.8. This is code of my html page:

```js
Dropzone.options.imagedropform = {
  paramName: 'file',
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  maxFilesize: 10, // MB
  maxFiles: 5
  };
```

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Image upload</title>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/imageuploadresources/customdropzone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/imageuploadresources/dropzone.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/imageuploadresources/dropzone.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="imagedropform" action="Upload" class="dropzone">
            <div class="dz-message">
                Drop files here or click to upload.
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my upload servlet following [this tutorial](http://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/java-drag-drop-image-file-upload-using-dropzone-js/):

```
@WebServlet("/Upload")
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request is not multipart, please 'multipart/form-data' enctype for your form.");
    }

    ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

    fileWriter.println(new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/images/"));
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
        fileWriter.println(items.toString());

        for (FileItem item : items) {
            fileWriter.println(item.toString()+"===="+item.getName());
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/images/", item.getName());
                item.write(file);

                System.out.println("uploaded");
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        fileWriter.close();
        out.close();
    }
}

}
}
```

some screenshots of my upload view
[initial output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXteP.png)
[image: image selected for upload]

If some solution using JSF (without Spring) is possible, please also suggest me. or some other easy to use good looking plugin for multiple image upload using JSF 2.2 (other than primefaces or some other faces) is also welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it after some search. In fact I was reading POST request data wrongly. Here is correct way to read multiple files upload request using [MultipartParser](http://www.servlets.com/cos/index.html) and example from [this link](http://www.thebook-demo.com/java-server/servlets/upload.html)

```
import com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.FilePart;
import com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser;
import com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.ParamPart;
import com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.Part;
// and other required classess
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request is not multipart, please 'multipart/form-data' enctype for your form.");
    }

    MultipartParser mp = new MultipartParser(request, 10*1024*1024); //10MB
    Part part;
    while ((part = mp.readNextPart()) != null) {
    String name = part.getName();
    if (part.isParam()) {
      // it's a parameter part
      ParamPart paramPart = (ParamPart) part;
      String value = paramPart.getStringValue();
      fileWriter.println("param; name=" + name + ", value=" + value);
    }
    else if (part.isFile()) {
      // it's a file part
      FilePart filePart = (FilePart) part;
      String fileName = filePart.getFileName();
      if (fileName != null) {
        // the part actually contained a file
        long size = filePart.writeTo(new File("/path to save directory"+filePart.getFileName()));
        System.out.println("file; name=" + name + "; filename=" + fileName +
          ", filePath=" + filePart.getFilePath() + 
          ", content type=" + filePart.getContentType() + 
          ", size=" + size);
      }
      else { 
        // the field did not contain a file
        System.out.println("file; name=" + name + "; EMPTY");
      }
    }
  }
}
```